# Applying Shadow When Dragged via Jquery UI Sortable

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I would like to add a "shadow" for the element that I drag using jQuery UI Sortable. This shadow essentially is over the area of *where the element would be* if the user dropped the element (not the currently dragged element itself). Trello implements this feature when users drag lists.

Does anyone know how this might be approached? I can see that we can access the dragged element (via `ui.item`), but I'm bothered by how we could access the box area it would be in if dropped. In my code, I have the following:

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#sortable-lists" ).sortable({
        start: function (event, ui) {
            ui.item.toggleClass('dragged');
        },

        stop: function (event, ui) {
            ui.item.toggleClass('dragged');
        },

        update: function (event, ui) {
            var data = $(this).sortable('serialize');
            var index = ui.item.index();

            ui.item.trigger('dropList', [ui.item.data('id'), index]);
           $.ajax({
                data: data+"&authenticity_token="+AUTH_TOKEN,
                type: 'PATCH',
                url: '/api/lists/update_order'
            });     
       }
    });
    $( "#sortable-lists" ).disableSelection();
  });
</script>
```

CSS:

```
.dragged {
  transform: rotate(3deg);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

here's how to get a shadow kind of effect. It will put a blurred rectangle in the list as a place holder while you're dragging an item. It will also make the item itself 50% opacity while you're dragging so that you can see the shadow through it.

js

```
yourlist.sortable({
        placeholder: 'sortable-placeholder',
        opacity: 0.5,
        sort: function(event, ui){
             $(".sortable-placeholder").height(ui.item.outerHeight());
        }
});
```

css

```
.sortable-placeholder { box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 20px 10px #fff; background-color: #bbb; min-height: 5em;}
```

Answer (score -1):

when you drag item using jquery ui sortable jquery create class call

> .ui-sortable-helper

to drag the item so all what you need to is to but your css in this class

like this

> .ui-sortable-helper {
>               box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 1px;
>           }

now you can put shadow in your selected item 
and for the place you will put the item use the class

> .ui-sortable-placeholder

and for more information you can check this example [Here](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/jquery-ui-sortable/) and [demo](http://demo.hongkiat.com/jquery-ui-sortable/)

hope to help you it's my first time to answer